# Finding the run length encoding for characters works on most of the test cases except one

Tags: python, string

For multiple repeating character string my code is working fine, but here is the scenario where  I give string "aaabba" the expected output is a3b2a1 but I get only a3b2. Please advise me as what is wrong in the code.

```
st = "aaabba"
n = len(st)
i = 0
while i < n - 1:
    count = 1   
    while (i < n-1 and st[i] == st[i+1]):
        count += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1
    print(st[i - 1] + str(count), end="")
```

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense. Please fix.

Comment: `while (i < n-1 ...)` - how do you expect to reach the last character if it isn't the same as the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in first while loop.
The code should be:

```
st = "aaabba"
n = len(st)
i = 0
while i < n:
    count = 1   
    while (i < n-1 and st[i] == st[i+1]):
        count += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1
    print(st[i - 1] + str(count), end="")
```

Comment: Thanking you for pointing it out, yes it should have either been  i <= n-1 or simply i < n, so that the last character also gets iterated and counted, in both the cases it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

message=input("Enter String for Run Length Encoding : ")

if not message:
    print("Enter Any String !!!")
    exit()
else :
    encode=""
    count=1

    for i in range(len(message)):
        if i+1!=len(message) and message[i]==message[i+1] and count<9:
            count=count+1
        else:
            encode=encode+str(count)+message[i]
            count=1

    print("Encoded message for ",message," : ",encode)

'''
Output:
>python test.py
Enter String for Run Length Encoding : wwwwaaadexxxxxx
Encoded message for  wwwwaaadexxxxxx  :  4w3a1d1e6x

>python test.py
Enter String for Run Length Encoding : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA11111111111111B
Encoded message for  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA11111111111111B  :  9A6A91511B

>python test.py
Enter String for Run Length Encoding : aaabba
Encoded message for  aaabba  :  3a2b1a
'''
```